# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, asynchronous, service, rxjs

Getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` when using a component in multiple place who subscribe a behaviour object for loading. Error occurs when component is loaded in one component and try to `load` or `destroy` in another component.

````js
@Component({
template: 'common.component.html',
selector: 'app-common'
})

export CommonComponent implements OnInit{

constructor(service: MyService){}

ngOnInit(){
}

}

**common.component.html**

<div>
    <div *ngIf="service.isLoading$ | async">Loading...</div>
</div>


**component 1**

<div>
    <app-common></app-common>
</div>

component 2

<div>
    <app-common></app-common>
</div>


@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  public isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
  public isLoading$ = this.isLoading.asObservable();
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public isLoading$ = this.isLoading.asObservable().pipe(delay(0))
```

more about it

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

Use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({template: 'common.component.html',
   selector: 'app-common',
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: Can you explain why OnPush is preferred here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move

```
<div *ngIf="service.isLoading$ | async">Loading...</div>
```

to another child component. That worked for me.